# Gram-Schmidt Process yielding strange vector

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

Let B = $\{(1,i,1),(2,-1,1+i)\}$. To find the orthonormal basis, I use the Gram-schmidt Process.

$\vec{u}_1$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,i,1)$

$\vec{u}_2$ = $\frac{1}{|(2,-1,1+i) - \frac{3 + 2i}{\sqrt{3}}(1,i,1)|}[(2,-1,1+i) - \frac{3 + 2i}{\sqrt{3}}(1,i,1)] = \frac{1}{|(2-\frac{3+2i}{\sqrt{3}}, -\frac{3+2i}{\sqrt{3}}, 1+i-\frac{3+2i}{\sqrt{3}})|}[(2-\frac{3+2i}{\sqrt{3}}, -\frac{3+2i}{\sqrt{3}}, 1+i-\frac{3+2i}{\sqrt{3}})]$

After this step, I'm fairly sure I'm doing something wrong here, I'm not sure how to evaluate $\vec{u}_2$ without it looking super ugly, or if I did the computation incorrectly. Wolfram alpha says that $\vec{u}_2 = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}(3-2i,1+3i,i)$ which I have no idea how to get to. Some guidance would be helpful!

Btw, this is my first Gram-Schmidt process I've ever done, so it's very likely I did something wrong.

Comment: If you need it, the full orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^3$ would be $$\left\{\ \tfrac1{\sqrt3}(1,i,1),\ \tfrac1{2\sqrt6}(3-2i,-1-3i,i),\ \tfrac1{2\sqrt2}(1,-1+i,-2-i)\ \right\}$$

Comment: Where did the third vector come from?

Comment: Since the span of the first two vectors has $0$ measure, almost any vector we choose will not be in that span.  I chose $(1,0,0)$ and completed the Gram-Schmidt process. If the random vector I chose happened to be in the span, I would simply choose another.

Comment: I see. Second, do you know what the error in my computation is?

Comment: The Monkey, since this comment list is getting too long, I have posted an answer with what I have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a minor mistake in your calculation.
$u_2=b_2-\frac{<b_2,u_1>}{<u_1,u_1>}u_1$ and as $<b_2,u_1> = \frac{(3+2i)}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $u_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,i,1)$, you have a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ factor missing in your expression. Answer will be $u_2=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}(3-2i,-1-3i,i)$

Comment: I was mistaken, $\vec{u}_1$ should be just the vector $(1,i,1)$, the normalizing process comes after. Also, I'm pretty sure it's $\frac{<b_2,u_1>}{<u_1,u_1>} = \frac{3+2i}{\sqrt{3}}$, so I'm still stuck with my original answer?

Comment: See, you can work with un normalized vectrors(and normalize at the end) but then $\frac{<b_2,u_1>}{<u1,u1>}=\frac{3+2i}{3}$ and you will use $u1=(1,i,1)$. When you are using normalized $u_1$ then $\frac{<b_2,u_1>}{<u1,u1>}=\frac{3+2i}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $u_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,i,1)$, which will make $u_2=b_2-\frac{3+2i}{3}(1,i,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

First we normalize the first vector:
$$
u_1=\frac1{\sqrt3}(1,i,1)
$$
Then compute the second vector:
$$
\begin{align}
u_2
&=\sqrt{\frac38}\left(\vphantom{\frac1{\sqrt3}}\right.(2,-1,1+i)-(2,-1,1+i)\cdot\overbrace{\frac1{\sqrt3}(1,-i,1)}^{\overline{u_1}}\overbrace{\color{#C00000}{\frac1{\sqrt3}}(1,i,1)}^{u_1}\left.\vphantom{\frac1{\sqrt3}}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt6}(3-2i,-1-3i,i)
\end{align}
$$
It seems you have left out a $\color{#C00000}{\frac1{\sqrt3}}$ from part of your computation.